# How do I iterate through this loop Get each Item Separately

Tags: php

I have this array I want to get the Values  "ABC" ,"1","2" and so on respectively and store them in separate variables.
I have used nested foreach but could not get it

```
    array(2) {
       [0] => array(3) {
          [0] => string(10) "ABC"
          [1] => string(1) "1"
          [2] => string(2) "2"
     } [1] => array(3) {
          [0] => string(10) "BCD118"
          [1] => string(1) "1"
          [2] => string(2) "9"
    }
   }
```

Comment: How would you like to call your variables, should they overwrite existing variables, and why would you want to convert such an easily accessible and structured array to a bunch of unrelated scalars (what problem are you trying to solve by this action)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your $_SESSION comment to Mike C,

```
foreach( $outer_array as $outer_key => $inner_array ) 
{
   foreach( $inner_array as $key => $value ) 
   {
      $_SESSION[$outer_key.'-'.$key] = $value;
   }
}
```

You would need unique keys though or (for instance) 'BCD118' and 'ABC' would both be key 0 and so 'ABC' would be overwritten.

**Edit**
You could append the `$outer_key` to the inner `$key` to get a unique $_SESSION key

This would produce key/value pairs

```
0-0 : ABC
0-1 : 1
0-2 : 2
1-0 : BCD118
1-1 : 1
2-2 : 9
```

Comment: @brianD:How can i overcome this situation

Comment: @braind: I have my Custom Session Function available  so when iam looping it i have to assign it to only the value .So in that array  i need to get each value key[0][0] should give me "ABC" so that i can set the the value ABC to one field

Comment: I don't think I quite follow what you are trying to do. But in any case, you should aim to have array keys that describe the value that they contain, especially for $_SESSIONS

Answer (score 4):

You could use a [`recursiveiteratoriterator`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php):

```
$it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($array));

foreach ($it as $key => $value) {
    echo $key . " - " . $value."\n";
}
```

Would give you:

```
0 - ABC
1 - 1
2 - 2
0 - BCD118
1 - 1
2 - 9
```

Comment: How Can i solve this "You would need unique keys though or (for instance) 'BCD118' and 'ABC' would both be key 0 and so 'ABC' would be overwritte"

Answer (score 1):

With foreach loops...

```
foreach ($array as $key=>$value) 
{
   foreach ($array[$key] as $subkey=>$subvalue) 
   {
      echo "$subkey $subvalue\n";
   }
}
```

Comment: How do assign the Key name with a string and its value  and put in a session

Answer (score 0):

Your array is of dimensions [2][3], so you should be able to do:

`for($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++)

{

for($o = 0; $o < 3; $o++)

{

$variable = $array[$i][$o];

}

}`

or an equivalent expression with foreach statements, depending on what you're trying to accomplish.

There are of course limitations from this, as you can really only write into another array. To get them into separate variables, you may just need to reference them statically.